# Port linking works but exposing a port doesn't (Docker)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, dockerfile, port

I'm trying to re-create a small company using Docker.
I want the Wordpress to be public, so it's using -p when configuring.
Now, I want the Finances website (OrangeHRM) to only be accessible from within the network. From my knowledge this should be possible by exposing the port instead of linking it.

But when I use expose I can't access the website from my machine, and when I link it using -p it is accessible.

Code with port linking

`docker run -d -v "/Docker_MKB/Docker/firefly/firefly_iii_upload":/var/www/html/storage/upload -p 8080:8080 -e APP_KEY=(redacted) -e DB_HOST=mariadb -e DB_PORT=3306 -e DB_CONNECTION=mysql -e DB_DATABASE=firefly -e DB_USERNAME=(redacted) -e DB_PASSWORD=(redacted) --network=isolated --name firefly jc5x/firefly-iii:latest`

Code with exposing port

`docker run -d -v "/Docker_MKB/Docker/firefly/firefly_iii_upload":/var/www/html/storage/upload -expose 8080 -e APP_KEY=(redacted) -e DB_HOST=mariadb -e DB_PORT=3306 -e DB_CONNECTION=mysql -e DB_DATABASE=firefly -e DB_USERNAME=(redacted) -e DB_PASSWORD=(redacted) --network=isolated --name firefly jc5x/firefly-iii:latest`

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you running the two applications in two separate `docker run` commands? I am not sure I entirely grok the problem, but I wonder if Docker Compose would be helpful here.

Comment: Is the only difference between the two commands that the first has `-p`, and the second has `-expose`?  "Expose" does almost nothing in modern Docker; if you don't have a `-p` option then the container won't be reachable from outside Docker.  From the first paragraph, though, that sounds like the behavior you want?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying is not possible. You need to publish a port for it to be accessible outside of your Docker container. You can read more about it [here](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-59-difference-between-exposing-and-publishing-ports)

> Now, I want the Finances website (OrangeHRM) to only be accessible from within the network. From my knowledge this should be possible by exposing the port instead of linking it.

You could do this on an application level by only allowing certain hosts to connect to your service, the allowed hosts can be identified with the service name instead of it's IP too if it is in the same network.

Comment: Is it maybe possible to have the Wordpress container on let's say both Network1 & Network2. And then have the MariaDB and Finances website (OrangeHRM) only on Network2?

Comment: @studentinneedofhelp23 To the best of my knowledge, even then you will have to publish the ports - just exposing them is not enough.